# Can i install Ubuntu on HTC Butterfly?

Tags: android, htc

After using Ubuntu on PC, I also wanted to try on my "HTC Butterfly".

But not dare to tried out what will happen or my data(Android OS) can be restore back or somethings else.

So surfing on Google for information but only other HTC devices (like HTC Desire hd, HTC Sensation, etc) are show that can install Ubuntu. If I can, I also want to dual boot on my android phone like PC!

I want more and detail information about "install ubuntu on HTC Butterfly" can be or cannot.

Can someone show me how exactly work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case if I were you I would wait for it to be released for it. Right now, Ubuntu for android has been released officialy it's their first release but it is for google nexus handsets. See below link:

[Ubuntu for Phone](http://www.ubuntu.com/phone/install)

Here is the list of Ubuntu Images for various android version's see it [also.](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images)

So, I would suggest you wait for a while till it gets to other devices as well.